# Unable to use graphic programming in codeblock

Tags: c++, codeblocks, bgi

```
#include<graphics.h>
#include<conio.h>
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
   int gd = DETECT, gm;
   initgraph(&gd, &gm, "c:\\TC\\BGI" );
   cout<<"Please Enter to continue..."<<endl;
   getch();
   closegraph();
   return 0;
}
```

All other programmes are running fine on my Codeblock 13.12, but when I run a simple graphic programme compiler crashes giving pop up window that says:

> "graphic.exe has stopped working window is checking solution".

It also giving a warning message on compilation:

> warning: deprecated conversion from string constant to 'char*' [-Wwrite-strings]|

How to resolve it?It is due to turbo C.

Comment: `<graphics.h>` & `<conio.h>`  are *not* standard C++11 headers. You may want to use a graphics toolkit library like [Qt](http://qt.io/) (it is free software, but not in the C++11 standard)

Comment: Have you already installed `winbgi` ? Are you sure you are linking against `libbgi.a` ? http://winbgim.codecutter.org/

Comment: About the warning, a string liiteral in treated as a constant string. That mean that you should never write `char *s = "A string litteral";`. Rather, write `const char *s = "A string litteral";` for example. So when a function like `initgraph` expects a `char *`, pass a modifiable string, not a constant one. So do for example: `char modifiable[] = "A string litteral";`. This will **copy** `"A string litteral"` (which is treated as constant) into the `modifiable` buffer, which is modifiable.

Comment: @mikedu95 No I haven`t installed winbgi i just copied the headers and lib file to its respective library in codeblock as told in instruction

Comment: @KamtaSahu *"I haven`t installed winbgi i just copied the headers and lib file to its respective library"*: You surely meant respective *directory*. And that's what *installation* is. However, are these files from WinBGIm or copied from Turbo C ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> It is due to turbo c.

Turbo c/c++ is ancient and didn't conform any standards. There are no such header files like `conio.h` or `graphics.h` for any modern c++ compilers.

Your codeblocks IDE most probably uses the GCC toolchain by default, which doesn't provide these headers.

You should lookup for more modern 3rd party libraries for handling graphics and raw keyboard input (e.g. something like SFML). The c++ standards have no notion about such stuff so far.

Comment: can you please provide me link for these GCC toolchain and Qt, or website where i can get.What are the other options like?

Answer (score 0):

For Graphics Programming In C You Need To Install Codeblocks-EP Version. Download From Here  http://codeblocks.codecutter.org/setup.exe

Install And Then Go File>New>Project>Winbgim project>GO>>Add Console>>NEXT . Give Project Name,location path And Click Finish. Now Again File >New>Empty File

Write Your C graphics Code>> Build And Run.

This Codeblocks has pre installed built in graphics libraries. So You need not to add anything.